# Enumerating points on the integer lattice, within a sphere, sorted by angle, in O(1) space

Tags: computational-geometry, space-complexity

Inspired by this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346135

(it was not clearly presented, and got closed)

Let's say I wanted to enumerate all the 3D points on the integer lattice, within a sphere, in order of the angle between the vector to the point and the up vector (say z).

Could I do this in O(1) space efficiently?

All I can find is:

```
Remembering last point (init at (0,0,0)). (O(1) memory)
while true
    init best dot product to 0
    going through all 3D points (three nested for's with radius range)
        if this point has better dot product but least or equal [caveat] than last point
            keep this point as best
    if best dot product is still 0, exit 
    pick best point as current point (this is where the listing occurs)
    update last point to best point
```

Not only is this absolutely slow, it also needs the use of integer math for dot product and length so that numerical precision doesn't mess with symmetrical points and it would also need a tweak to guarantee symmetrical points are listed in a known order.

Is there any good algorithms that would apply here?

Comment: What are the constraints on your sphere relative to the lattice? Is the center of the sphere a lattice point, or can it be arbitrary? Is the radius of the sphere integral?

Comment: The sphere is centred at (0,0,0). We can set the radius integral for simplicity (it would be trivial to filter the points as a post-process anyway, if the radius was a real value)

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can do this in $O(R^2)$ time and space: for each feasible $(x,y)$, maintain the next $z$: at each iteration, just select the next one. I'm really not sure you can do this in $O(1)$ or even $O(R)$ space.

Comment: To get constant space efficiency, what you would need is an efficient algorithm to find the circle that contains the next points when given a point inside the sphere. I think you can look at the cone centered around the z-axis with the apex at the origin and find the lattice point closest to this cone. A simple way to do this is to inspect all lines parallel to the z-axis that at find the largest point inside the cone. This gets you $O(r^2\log r)$ time by using binary search on these lines, perhaps you can get it down to $O(\log^3 r)$ by using more binary searches.

Comment: Actually, do you need it ti be precise? If you allow some error (for vectors whose angle are close), there may be a simple solution. Also, do you mean points on the sphere or inside the ball?

Comment: Inside. And yeah, precise.